# Xcode files missing

Tags: xcode, finder

After running the project to take a look at the app on xcode, I found the majority of the files missing (name written in red). Among those files there were some cells, view controllers, pods, info.plist, app delegate, etc. I tried to search them on Finder but couldn't find them as well on project folder. I tried to cd Desktop the project on terminal to open the podfile but was unsuccessful as well. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you rename something (project or folder) or move something on disk? Did you check the Trash for the files?

Comment: I didn’t rename anything nor moved or deleted. Also couldn’t find anything on finder or bin. Yesterday I switched users but it wasn't the first time and never caused any problems before.